# Is $E=-V/d$ or $E=V/d$ in an equal electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage

Is $E=-V/d$ or $E=V/d$ in an equal electric field, and is the voltage from $a$ to $b$ defined as the electric potential of $a$ minus that of $b$, or the opposite?

After having done a couple of problems in my workbook, I can't figure out which it is, and I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Voltage is difference in potential. What sign you put on it just depend on which direction that is relevant for you. Do you have a specific example we can look at?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/efromv.html#c1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is the voltage from $a$ to $b$ defined as the electric potential of $a$ minus that of $b$, or the opposite?

Voltage $V$ is **difference in electric potential $V_i$**:

$$\text{Voltage from } a \text{ to } b=V=V_b-V_a$$

A difference is always "last minus first" or "final minus initial". Because, if you look at a tree 10 metres away, and a bench 7 metres away, then you want to subtract the 7 initial metres that are *not* between them but *before* the first one from the 10 metres.

> Is $E=−V/d$ or $E=V/d$ in an equal electric field

It can be both. It depends on what your scenario is. Remember that voltage is *energy (work $W$) required per charge $q$*. We could write your formula as:

$$E=\frac{W}{q}/d$$

- Let a charge be pushed by the electric field $E$ through the distance $d$, and positive work $W>0$ is done (energy is added, the charge speeds up).
- Move the charge *against* the electric field, and you must *spend* work $W$ to do so, so $W<0$ is done by the field.

Now, replace $W/q$ with $V$ in both cases, and you'll see the sign. One version of the formula applies in the case where the charge flows along with, the other version when the charge flows against the field. It shouldn't matter much; as long as you are aware of whether energy is added or removed, you can easily use this formula and add the sign where needed in other contexts. [See more in various internet articles](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elewor.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, you made it very clear.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of definitions, the sign is negative as in the answer from The Photon. However, in terms of how this works out in actual examples, it is an example of the situation that almost always arises when dealing with signs in physics. The only way to get signs right is to think carefully about the physical situation and definitions of the basic quantities. There is no automatic mathematical machine that will come to the rescue.

In the present case, the electric field points in the direction that a positive charge would move if it were placed in the field, and electric potential is defined such that this is the direction 'downhill' from the point of view of electric potential. That is, the electric field points from a place at higher potential towards a place at lower potential. As long as your mathematical statements express this, then they are correct (at least, the sign is correct). If they do not express this, then they are not correct.

Let's apply this reasoning to a parallel-plate capacitor. It is reasonably obvious that the electric field between the plates points from the positively charged plate to the negatively charged plate, because a small positive charge placed in betweeen the plates will be repelled by the first and attracted to the second. Since this direction is 'downhill' from the point of view of electric potential, we must conclude that the electric potential is higher on the positive plate. This also agrees with what you would think if you consider such a capactor connected to a battery (a voltage source). The positive terminal on the battery has the higher electric potential.

Answer (score 0):

The electrostatic potential difference between points $a$ and $b$ is defined as

$$V_{ab}=-\int_b^a\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

To remember the sign, consider that if $\vec{E}$ points from $a$ to $b$, then you would have to do work on a charged particle to move it from $b$ to $a$, therefore you know the potential at $a$ is higher than at $b$.